# Display Foreign key and ManyToMany relation in Django template

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-templates

model.py

```
class Record(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, blank=True)
    ...

class Item(models.Model):
    PAYMENT_CLASSIFICATION = (
                             ('earning','Earning'),
                             ('deduction','Deduction'),
                             ('reimbursement','Reimbursement')
                             )
    payment_classification = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, 
                                              choices=PAYMENT_CLASSIFICATION)
    user_to_input = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    ...

class EachRowItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)  
    record = models.ForeignKey(Record,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)     
    paid_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places =2, null=True, blank=True )  
    unit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places =2, null=True, blank=True )
```

form.py

```
class EachRowItemForm(forms.ModelForm):     
    class Meta: 
        model = EachRowItem
        exclude = ['record']
```

view.py

```
def PayRecordUpdate(request, pk):
    form = EachItemForm(request.POST or None) 
    record = Record.objects.get(pk=pk)
    
    if request.is_ajax():
        item = request.POST.get('item')
        paid_amount = request.POST.get('paid_amount')
        unit = request.POST.get('unit')
            if form.is_valid():
                record = Record.objects.get(pk=pk)
                instance = form.save(commit=False)
                instance.record = record
                record.items.add(item)
                record.save()
                instance.save()
                return JsonResponse({
                    'item': instance.item,
                    'paid_amount': instance.paid_amount,
                    'unit': instance.unit,
                    })
    context ={
            'record': record,
            'form':form,
             }
    return render(request, '/update_record.html', context)
```

In the template I have a popup Modal to fill in the EachItemForm form. Therefore there is is_ajax(). I can get the valid form.

| Item | paid amount | unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Earning |  |  |
| Item A1 | 2.00 | 2 |
| Item A2 | 1.00 | 2 |
| ----- | ----------- | ---- |
| Deduction |  |  |
| Item B1 | -2.00 | 1 |
| Item B2 | -1.00 | 1 |
| ----- | ----------- | ---- |
| Reimbursement |  |  |
| Item C1 | 2.00 | 1 |
| Item C2 | 1.00 | 1 |

However, I having problem to render in update_record.html where the items are arranged to classification accordingly. The function has to be in such a way that the item is setup in different page. For example, ItemB1 is set deduction. The record can add whatever items in update_record.html template. The item could have different amount and unit, needed to be key-in in the EachItemForm form for the record.

I have tried below but result is not I needed. I'm not so sure whether the model foreign key or model setup could be done in more easier way or need to render a filtered query into template. Kindly please help.

```
{% if record.items.all %}
   {% for item in record.items.all %}      # In the Record__Item now then how to access Item__EachRowItem from here?
   {% if item.payment_classification == "earning" %}
        {{ item }}
        {{ item.paid_amount }}
        {{ item.unit }}
   {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}                 
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hello @bewbie did my answer solved your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your `views.py` like this for example if you want to access certain values from `Item` table you have to do something like this

```
obj = Record.objects.get(pk=id)
obj.items.values('id') #or many values you can add for eg. ('id','payment_classification')
```

or

if you want to access all rows than you have to do like this

```
obj = obj.items.all()
```

and in your template you have to access like this

```
{% for i in obj %}
{{ i.user_to_input }}
{% endfor %}
```